# Regex: Capture a line when certain columns are equal to certain values

Tags: python, regex

Let's say we have this data extract:

```
ID,from,to,type,duration
1,paris,berlin,member,12
2,berlin,paris,member,12
3,paris,madrid,non-member,10
```

I want to retrieve the line when **from = paris**, and **type = member**.
Which means in this example I have only:

```
1,paris,berlin,member,12
```

That satisfy these rules. I am trying to do this with Regex only. I am still learning and I could only get this:

```
^.*(paris).*(member).*$
```

However, this will give me also the second line where paris is a destination.

The idea I guess is to:

- Divide the line by commas.
- Check if the second item is equal to 'paris'
- Check if the fourth item is equal to 'member', or even check if there is 'member' in that line as there is no confusion with this part.

Any solution where I can use **only** regex?

Comment: Don't do this with regex. Use the `csv` module to read each line into a dictionary, then test the elements you care about.

Comment: I know I can do that simply with csv, but I am trying to learn how to solve this with only regex.

Comment: using `regex` is overkilling here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^,]*` instead of `.*` to match a sequence of characters that doesn't include the comma separator. Use this for each field you want to skip when matching the line.

```
^[^,]*,paris,[^,]*,member,
```

Note that this is a very fragile mechanism compared to use the `csv` module, since it will break if you have any fields that contain comma (the `csv` module understands quoting a field to protect the delimiter).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^.*,(paris),.*,(member),.*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = """
 ID,from,to,type,duration
 1,paris,berlin,member,12
 2,berlin,paris,member,12
 3,paris,madrid,non-member,10
"""
final_data = re.findall('\d+,paris,\w+,member,\d+', s)
```

Output:

```
['1,paris,berlin,member,12']
```

However, note that the best solution is to read the file and use a dictionary:

```
import csv
l = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))
final_l = [dict(zip(l[0], i)) for i in l[1:]]
final_data = [','.join(i[b] for b in l[0]) for i in final_l if i['from'] == 'paris' and i['type'] == 'member']
```

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out, I would read this into a dictionary using csv. However, if you insist on using regex, this should work:

```
[0-9]+\,paris.*[^-]member.*
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
import re
regex = r"\d,paris,\w+,member,\d+"
str = """ID,from,to,type,duration
1,paris,berlin,member,12
2,berlin,paris,member,12
3,paris,madrid,non-member,10"""
str = str.split("\n")

for line in str:
    if (re.match(regex, line)):
        print(line)
```